# How can I launch .sh scripts from the finder in iTerm2 instead of Terminal?

Tags: finder, command-line, iterm

I have set 'always open with' to : 'Iterm2', for .sh files in osX.
Although a double click on a shell script now opens a new Iterm window, the script does not actually run, I just the get the empty prompt.
There might be an applescript solution, but I would prefer a more direct way.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me but only if the file is executable. For example this runs `a.sh` in a new window:

```
echo say a>a.sh;chmod +x a.sh;open a.sh -a iTerm
```

If you want it to work with non-executable files, set an application like this as the default application for `.sh` files:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I followed your instructions, even though my .sh files are already executable. Unfortunately : same result, it does open the iTerm window but just an empty prompt again!  It seems that iTerm does not listen to the argument, but I can't find any relevant setting inside iTerm. Are you using Iterm2 ?